# Create linked tables in Access to SQL server via application role

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create linked tables to SQL Server tables in MS Access via a VBA script. Currently, I have the following, which works perfectly:

```
strConnect = "ODBC;DSN=xxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" & _
                        "APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=myDB;ApplicationIntent=READONLY;"
    aSourceTable = Array("dmy.Tab1", "dmy.Tab2", "dmy.Tab3", "dmy.Tab4")

    For X = 0 To UBound(aSourceTable)
        Set t = New TableDef
        t.Connect = strConnect
        t.NAME = Replace(aSourceTable(X), "dmy.", "") ' remove schema
        t.SourceTableName = aSourceTable(X)
        CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append t
    Next X
```

Where xxx is the data server name and myDB is the database I want to connect to.

Now I'm trying to recreate the same linked tables, but the ODBC connection to the SQL server has to go through an **application role** (which already has been created in SQL). Any ideas on how to go about this? I've tried populating the UID/Password parameter in the connection string, but that doesn't seem to work.

I've already created the application role:

Name - tempapprole

Pwd - temppassword

Many thanks,

Nick

Comment: To use an application role you need to run `sp_setapprole` after you connect. Do you know how to run stored procedure in your code? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-setapprole-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the reply; yes I do. The only bit I'm unsure of is where to fit this in if I'm creating the link via VBA. If I run an execute statement after the "t.Connect" statement, is that what you had in mind? I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: This says it might not be possible: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=15249 This describes how to do it in an ADP. But you'd need to reqrite for an ADP (they are excellent but depracated in MS Access) https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/308312/how-to-use-application-roles-with-access-projects-and-sql-server-2000. You many need to negotiate with your admin. `sp_setapprole` is really not that secure given that it's in clear text in your code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks, that's very helpful. Even if the code/database is securely locked down?

Comment: What do you mean by locked down? Nothing in MS Access or MS Access VBS is really locked down. You can download VBA password crackers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me to connect to MS SQL-Server:

```
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=" & myDB & ";UID=" & tempapprole & ";PWD=" & temppassword
Conn.Provider = "msdasql"
Conn.Open
```

Comment: It does not address the application role aspect

Answer (score -1):

You can try as follows-

```
Dim strConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
strConnect.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data 
source=TABELS.mdb"
strConnect.Open()
aSourceTable = Array("dmy.Tab1", "dmy.Tab2", "dmy.Tab3", "dmy.Tab4")

For X = 0 To UBound(aSourceTable)
    Set t = New TableDef
    t.Connect = strConnect
    t.NAME = Replace(aSourceTable(X), "dmy.", "") ' remove schema
    t.SourceTableName = aSourceTable(X)
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append t
Next X
```

Comment: In what way does this use an application role? For starters he's connecting to SQL Server, not MS Access.

Comment: For one, `New OleDb.OleDbConnection` is .Net and not available in VBA. This answer is invalid.